# Chromedriver to pickup existing Chrome browser session in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I want to open several weblinks under a website in 1 browser (several tabs). The website requires login and password.

When login and password keyed in. it turns to a verification page, asks for the verification code sent to me by email.

I checked the email and key in verification code on the verification page. Login is successful.

The existing browser is in front of me.

However the codes are not picking it up, and open another tab as wanted. Seems a certain connection is lost.

How can I continue? (or as an alternative, how can Python to reuse the existing Chrome browser?)

The codes usually works well but comes to this case (login, enter verification code), it doesn't.

```
import os, time
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Chrome
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chromedriver = "C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver

opts = ChromeOptions()                                         # leave browser open after code
opts.add_experimental_option("detach", True)                   # leave browser open after code
opts.add_argument('disable-infobars')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver, chrome_options=opts)  # leave browser open after code

driver.maximize_window()

verificationErrors = []
accept_next_alert = True

time.sleep(5)

base_url = "https://awebsite.com/"
driver.get(base_url)
window_0 = driver.window_handles[0]
driver.switch_to_window(window_0)
driver.find_element_by_id("username").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys("username")
driver.find_element_by_id("password").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element_by_id("Submit").click()

time.sleep(60)

driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
window_1 = driver.window_handles[1]
driver.switch_to_window(window_1)
time.sleep(3)
driver.get('https://anotherwebsite.com')
time.sleep(3)

sys.exit()
```

Comment: So what do you want to do? Just switch between two tabs and handle both within single session?

Comment: @Andersson, thank you. I will open a new tab and fill the form there. But the problem is, I can't even open a new tab.

Comment: Hi Mark. May I trouble you to make your questions more succinct? We do not add greetings or thanks here, since we are aiming for a technical style of writing, rather than a forum/discussion style. If you can refrain, that will give volunteer editors less work to do. Thanks!

Comment: There is also a discussion on [home-made title tagging here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253028/472495) - the summary is that we prefer titles not to include their own tagging systems, since that's the purpose of the question's proper tags.

Comment: @halfer, thank you for the note. I just want to be thankful as many kind people spent time and efforts, and sharing their knowledge. Could you please suggest a way that I can do so, meanwhile keeping the question neat?

Comment: Great. If you are interested, there's further information on Meta ([here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it)). Thanks is best expressed in voting, accepting, or participating in useful comment conversation. Although we discourage comments to be used for thanks on their own (see the guidance in an empty comment) it is fine to add it in before some other material, like you've done now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below to perform some actions on two different pages/tabs:

```
# Handle base page
base_url = "https://awebsite.com/"
driver.get(base_url)
window_0 = driver.current_window_handle
...

# Handle new page
driver.execute_script('window.open("https://anotherwebsite.com");')
window_1 = [window for window in driver.window_handles if window != window_0][0]
driver.switch_to_window(window_1)
# driver.close() # To close new tab
...

# Switch back to base page
driver.switch_to_window(window_0)
```